# How to keep javamail connection in android?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I used javamail api in my android project and parse String in "mail subject" and "mail content". In my gmail there are many mail boxes such as travel, job, photo....  I need go through all mail boxes and search mails in my conditions. But I found when call **getData()** it will login gmail and make connection again.

My question are

1.How can it Keep connection in android?

2.How can I search all the mail boxes in the same time?

***Thanks for help.***

```
private String downloadUrl () throws IOException {

    receiveMail("username", "password");
    return null; 
}
```

receiveMail part

```
    private static List<Message> receiveMail(String username, String Password) {

    try {

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", IMAPS_PROTOCOL);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null );
        session.setDebug(false);
        final Store store = session.getStore(IMAPS_PROTOCOL);
        store.connect(IMAPS_MAIL_HOTS , username, Password);

        getData(store, "travel");
        getData(store, "job");            
        getData(store, "photo");

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: UPDATE:

But, I got a new problem. I put getData() into thread for search all mail boxes in the same time. It seems can't wait to close the folder before opening the next folder.
How can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse a single connection for each folder, you need to be sure to close the folder before opening the next folder.