# Is any solution in javamail for search all the mail boxes in the same time?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I try to search all the mail boxes in the same time.
But, in thread it's doesn't work.
because I need keep connection. [before question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788895/how-to-keep-javamail-connection-in-android)

**Does anyone have any solution for this problem?**

THANKS,

Comment: all the mail boxes means you want to get mail have same time from different email addresses ?. am i wrong ?

Comment: I mean one account with many inbox

Comment: upto my knowledge of mail provider and mail api "inbox" is a just folder and you can not create multiple folder named inbox, than how "many inbox" possible.

Comment: "many inbox" is created by me for classification.  such as travel, job, photo....

Answer (score 0):

this'll help you

```
SearchTerm olderThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT, someFutureDate);
SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, somePastDate);
SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(olderThan, newerThan);
your_folder.search(andTerm);
```

and thread doesn't affect in your mechanism if you are using properly.

Comment: If I do this. That's fine.
`
            getData(store, "travel");
            getData(store, "job");
            getData(store, "photo");
            ......
`
 If I put getData() in thread.The connection will be reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

There's no single JavaMail method that will search all mailboxes at once, because the underlying IMAP protocol doesn't support such an operation.  You need to iterate over all the mailboxes and search each one separately.  Use the Store.getDefaultFolder() method to get the top level folder and the Folder.list() method to get a list of all the folders.